# Making a get request from API in electron.js + react.js vite, when user enters the infromation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, vite

I am building a cross platform application using electronjs with reactjs + vite. At this point, I have successfully achieved making a get request from the API and rendering it in the component where I want to show data.

But what I need to do is to have an input, where user types code, for example 12345 and this code will replace API URL: [https://test.com/api/test/{code}](https://test.com/api/test/%7Bcode%7D) instead of code to be https://test.com/api/test/12345 or whatever user types.

I am making a get request via axios in main.ts and there I want to pass my input, which I have in the redux slice, so when user types numbers in the component where i render input, this function runs:

```js
const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    dispatch(setInput(value));
};
```

and I want to have something like this: `https://test.com/api/test/${input}`.

How correct is that and what's the best way to do it? I tried directly importing input with `useSelector` but it did not work.

All the API URL is not real of course just showing as an example.